# How to turn an integer into a double in ATS?

Tags: ats

Could someone tell me how to implement the following
function in ATS:

```
fun int2double (x: int): double
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am testing stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the target language you want to compile to.

If you compile to C, you can just do:

```
staload
UN = "prelude/SATS/unsafe.sats"

fun int2double(x: int): double = $UN.cast(x)
```

If you compile to JavaScript, then int2double is already defined.

Answer (score 2):

I think you once said following is better manner...

```
fun int2double(x: int): double = $UN.cast{double}(x)
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete the previous two comments?

Comment: You should be able to do that by clicking the "delete this comment" button that appears when hovering on the comment.

Comment: I don't see anything hovering right now; maybe I have not earned the privilege yet :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, one can simply use whatever is available in the target language to implement the needed function. For instance, say you have the following function in C:

```
double int2double_in_c(int x) { return (double)x; }
```

Then you can declare the following one in ATS:

```
fun int2double(x: int): double = "mac#int2double_in_c"
```

For each call to int2double in ATS, the compiler generates a call to int2double_in_c in the generated code. The same applies if you want to compile to JS, Python, PHP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling to C code, then you'll have to use something like the following:

```
fun int2double(x:int): double = g0int2float_int_double (x)
```

which is a built-in function (see `$ATSHOME/prelude/SATS/float.sats` for details).